# Python text out of TD error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' WHY?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

i have a piece of code that I run through different urls. Now I get an error when I try to extract the text or a td. What am I doing wrong?

ERROR

```
year = container.find('td', attrs={"class" : "label"}).text 
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

CODE

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(results.text, "html.parser")
autos = soup.find('div', {"class" : "specleft"})


titles = []
years = []
time = []

movie_div = autos.find_all('tr')

#our loop through each container
for container in movie_div:
    #year
    year = container.find('td', attrs={"class" : "label"}).text
    years.append(year)

    time1 = container.find('td', attrs={"class" : "data"})
    time.append(time1)

print(years)
print(time)
```

OUTPUT

```
[<td class="label">Original Base Price</td>, <td class="label">No. Produced</td>, None, <td class="label">Body Maker</td>, <td class="label">No. Doors</td>, <td class="label">Passengers</td>, <td class="label">Model Number</td>, <td class="label">Weight</td>, None, <td class="label">Wheelbase</td>, <td class="label">Length</td>, <td class="label">Width</td>, <td class="label">Height</td>, <td class="label">Front Tread</td>, <td class="label">Rear Tread</td>, None, <td class="label">Type</td>, <td class="label">Displacement</td>, <td class="label">Cylinders</td>, <td class="label">Bore &amp; Stroke</td>, <td class="label">Compression Ratio-Std</td>, <td class="label">Compression Ratio-Opt</td>, <td class="label">Brake Horsepower</td>, <td class="label">Rated Horsepower</td>, <td class="label">Torque</td>, <td class="label">Main Bearings</td>, <td class="label">Valve Lifters</td>, <td class="label">Block Material</td>, <td class="label">Engine Numbers</td>, <td class="label">Engine No. Location</td>, <td class="label">Lubrication</td>, None, <td class="label">Type</td>, <td class="label">Make</td>, None, <td class="label">Type</td>, <td class="label">Drive</td>, <td class="label">No. Of Gears</td>, <td class="label">Gear Ratios</td>, <td class="label">1st</td>, <td class="label">2nd</td>, <td class="label">3rd</td>, <td class="label">4th</td>, <td class="label">5th</td>, <td class="label">Reverse</td>]
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the find method returned None at some point. You can first check for None before getting the text. Something like this.

```
td_label = container.find('td', attrs={"class" : "label"})
text = "no text"
if td_label:
    text = td_label.text
```